# UPS: Do i require a special extension cord for power in?

Tags: cable, ups

I have a couple of Tripplite UPS systems.

The power in cables are bright orange and about 2 meters in length. I want to put the system on the other side of the room but for some reason the UPS keep "going off" over there.

So I guess the wall power sockets on that side of the room are a little dodgy.

So i figured Id just go online and get some replacement UPS power IN (from wall to  UPS) cables of an appropriate length. But i cant find any anywhere. (auction sites, tripplite store, cable websites).

So now I'm wondering if that's just because you can use a standard extension cord of an appropriate wattage?

I thought the UPS power IN cables were "special". Is that not so?

Comment: Just use a good extension cord that's of a heavy gauge wire.  What makes you think the power cables are "special"?  They're just carrying electricity from your wall. :)

Comment: Yep, a good, heavy-duty extension cord.  Basically, unless these units are monsters, an 18-gauge cord could handle them, but I'd recommend you get at least a 16-gauge and maybe 14-gauge.  You want 3-prong extensions of the type that might be used for power tools.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the UPS keeps "going off"?  Are you tripping a circuit breaker?  You need an extension cord that rated for the load, but that's so it doesn't get too hot and cause a fire.  Having an undersized extension cord shouldn't cause the UPS to shut itself off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get one appropriately rated for the maximum draw the UPS can handle. An "air conditioner" extension cord should be enough for medium-size UPSes, but always check the specs yourself to be sure.